# Apps Script HTMLService not working and it was working perfectly

Tags: google-apps-script

I have created a lot of apps using Apps Script and HTMLService for my work and all the apps have been working perfectly(reports,submission tools,trackers,etc) however, since Feb 25th,2014 they are not working, not even a single one of them.

When I click the button of a html form in my app it should load another page but now I click on the link and nothing happen, I really need your help since I dont know why they are not working when they used to work without any inconvenient.

Below you can find a code that worked before and now is not working,

Code.gs

```
function doGet() {
var template=  HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('test');
template.action = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
return template.evaluate()
}

function doPost(e){
var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('test.html');
template.action = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
return template.evaluate(); 
}
```

test.html

`<!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
      <body>
        Exception Tracker Report <br/><br/>
        <form >
          <input name = "test" value="test">
          Test<input type="submit" value="Load" />
        </form>
      </body>
   </html>`

I really request your help in this matter since all the apps that I have created using HTMLService are not working (20 or more apps).

Once again, the code above should work without any problem but I dont know if there have been changes in the HTMLService Google class or anything regarding this.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google made a change yesterday on htmlservice, by defect if not mentioned the sandbox mode was emulated. They changed it to native.
As it's not mentioned in your script, you where running in emulated mode and since yesterday ... it changed to native mode.
You need to specify in your script that you want to use the emulated mode.

this way:

```
function doGet() {
var template=  HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('test');
template.action = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
return template.evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.EMULATED);
}
```

Comment: to complete the post: http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.fr/2014/02/more-apps-script-apis-and-features.html